# Model saved after training using Keras fit_generator doesn't give predictions properly

Tags: python, keras, translation

I am using `fit_generator` to train a translation model. The generator code is added below.

class My_Generator(Sequence):

```
def __init__(self, X_data, Y_data, batch_size):
    self.X_data, self.Y_data = X_data, Y_data
    #print(X_data)
    self.batch_size = batch_size

def __len__(self):
    print(int(ceil(len(self.X_data) / float(self.batch_size))))
    return int(ceil(len(self.X_data) / float(self.batch_size)))

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    #print('hey')
    batch_x = self.X_data[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_y = self.Y_data[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
    hindi_data= encode_sequences(hin_tokenizer,batch_x,hin_max_len_sent)
    eng_data = encode_sequences(eng_tokenizer,batch_y,eng_max_len_sent)
    output = encode_output(eng_data,eng_vocab_size)

    return array(hindi_data),array(output)
```

I have trained for 30 epochs which gave `val_loss: 0.5665` and `val_acc: 0.9268`.

Prediction code:

```
  def predict_sequence(model, tokenizer, source):
     prediction = model.predict(source, verbose=0)[0]
     integers = [argmax(vector) for vector in prediction]
     target = list()
     for i in integers:
        word = word_for_id(i, tokenizer)
     print('target ' ,word)
     if word is None:
        break
     target.append(word)
     return ' '.join(target)
```

The saved model doesn't give proper predictions for the target language. I get a bleu of 0. I tried using `predict_generator` as well. But this also doesn't seem to work. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, you used the model to predict on validation set after training?

Comment: Can you add bit of code, how you implemented generator, and how you feed the data for prediction.

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B I have tried predicting on both training and validation dataset gave.Both resulted in a bleu of 0

Comment: @Priyanka did you save the best model? You can turn off shuffle in your generator.

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B yes I did set the ModelCheckPoint save_best_only option to True

Comment: @Priyanka what is 'source'? Numpy array with encoded values?

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B Sorry that I didn't mention. yes source is a numpy array returned from the encoded_sequences